# Uniswap V3 sqrtPrice for ETH/DAI and ETH/USDT, ETH/USDC vastly different

Tags: blockchain, uniswap

I use `IUniswapV3PoolState.slot0` to return sqrtPriceX96 and tick for different pairs in Uniswap V3. The results are very reasonable for ETH/DAI, but it's quite different for ETH/USDT and ETH/USDC.

This is not because of the order of the tokens, but rather the final result of price (after taking care of square root and Q96) differ by 10^(-12). So I would get ETH/DAI around $3200, while ETH/USDT and ETH/USDC will give $3200*10^(-12). Is there anything I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about math/3rd party service implementation, not about programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EVM compatible blockchains use fixed-point math. The floating point values that you see in the UI are abstractions, technically everything is an integer; a specific number of digits reserved to represent the decimals. Different ERC-20 tokens reserve a different number of decimals.

- WETH and DAI have 18 decimals
- USDT and USDC have 6 decimals.

If you have asset X that has 6 and an asset Y that has 18 decimals, then the price of Y in terms of X has to be corrected for this fact.

Lets use `price = y/x`, then the price adjusted for the amount of decimals is going to be `price_adjusted = y/x * 10^(-12)`. To see why refer to [Section 3.3.2 here](http://atiselsts.github.io/pdfs/uniswap-v3-liquidity-math.pdf):

[image: Price adjusted for decimal equation]